# Parenthetical statement that expresses a condition

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am studying a book and one of the lines (which was written in the 30's) is,

> We had admitted that we were powerless over alcohol — that our lives had become unmanageable.

My question is whether or not it is to read this as two separate statements — meaning one could be true and not the other; or does it mean if the first is true then the second is also true?

Answer (score 4):

The second clause is an emphasis, expansion or elucidation of the first. It's not an alternative.

> We had admitted that we were powerless over alcohol. We had admitted that our lives had become unmanageable.

Their lives had become unmanageable because of alcohol's power over them.

Comment: +1 For a technical term: the second *that* clause is [**in apposition to**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) the first *that* clause.

Comment: Another textbook example of [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60644/15299), omitting the repeated subject, auxiliary, and verb in the second clause. _And_ is optional, and here is signalled by the intonation instead.